# eliminating duplicates from plsql associative arrays

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to avoid storing duplicate values in plsql associative array.
For example: When processing and adding values in a loop, if the array already contains the element value, that value should not be stored recognizing that such element already exists in the plsql table.

For ex: if the array has stored the word USA during a loop processing, then if conditions become such that USA again is the answer in the next iteration of the loop, then it should not be stored as it exists already.

Likewise, if GER does not exist(again,based on some lookup), then it gets stored for the first time, but not subsequently.

I tried looking up "exists", but it expects a parameter element number/position or i could be wrong in its usage. Is there a way to check the entire collection and determine if a value exists before storing it?

- Casey

Comment: What does the key in your associative array represent?  Could you define the collection such that the value (USA, GER) is the key and the value is just a boolean that is always `true`?  Then you just have to look at the set of keys that are defined.  If you're using an associative array but the key is not meaningful (if it is just an increasing integer for example), you may be better off with a nested table using multiset operations.

Comment: The key is not meaningful and can increase...It just stores the values as they come in based on certain lokkup logic. The only condition is for it to be unique. Its ok to actually let it fill up with duplicate values and have the ability to reomve them in one shot as a final step even. I did not understand your subsequent statement of nested table using multiset operations. Can you please point me to an example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to change the definition of your associative array so that the value you are trying to ensure is unique is the key.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  TYPE country_aat IS TABLE OF boolean
    INDEX BY varchar2(3);
  l_countries country_aat;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (<<query that returns country codes>>)
  LOOP
    l_countries( i.country_code ) := true;
  END LOOP;
```

At this point, you can iterate through the keys of `l_countries` and see the distinct country codes that were found.

Another option would be to use a nested table and use a `MULTISET` operation.  For example

```
DECLARE
  TYPE country_nt IS TABLE OF varchar2(3);
  l_countries country_nt;
BEGIN
  <<populate l_countries>>

  l_countries := l_countries MULTISET INTERSECT DISTINCT l_countries;
END;
```

The last step will eliminate the non-distinct entries.  One of the two right-hand tables could also be an empty collection of `country_nt`-- that would probably be more efficient but would require declaring an additional local variable.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks Justin. The nested table multiset approach seems neat. I made it work with this approach.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to say: extend the nested table collection only if a value is found to be collected (after lookup logic). I see a situation right now where there are lots of null elements in the collection.

Comment: Another neat way after further researching is to use "SET" operator on nested table collection instead of using multiset to remove duplicates. l_countries := set(l_countries); also works.